# Terms to distinguish Java programming language monitor and wait/notify monitors

Tags: java, concurrency, monitor

I am having issues with the terms for the Java monitors. First of all I distinguish between two kinds of monitors:

- those who can be acquired by using `wait()`
- those who can be acquired by the `synchronized` block

The **monitor** itself is an object, on which `wait()` or `synchronized` is called on. How can these two types of monitors be distinguished? In the [JVMTI API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html) they write:

> "monitor" means Java programming language object monitor.

This does not help me. However, further they use the terms Monitor and Contended Monitor to distinguish them at least in the API in terms of function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, these are the same thing.  They are variously called **monitors**, **mutexes** and (in Java) **primitive locks**, and these terms mean pretty much the same thing in current usage.

The primary usage pattern involving a mutex with threads calling `wait()` and `notify()` is referred to as a **condition**, but the same mutex can simultaneously be used as a simple region of mutual exclusion.

The phrase "**contended** monitor" refers to a monitor / mutex / primitive lock where there is contention over the region of mutual exclusion.  Or to put it more simply, where one thread holds the mutex, and others are waiting to acquire it.

Wikipedia references:

- [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)
- [Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex)
- [Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)

(It should be noted that these pages are not definitive, and not entirely consistent.  But then most IT folks play "fast and loose" with terminology, and very few people have read the original publications.  But hey ... that's how language evolves.)

Answer (score 1):

They are both the same thing.  The "monitor" provides both functions.  Notice that the VM instructions for a `synchronized` block are called `monitorenter` and `monitorexit`

Contention can happen on `monitorenter` (i.e. entering the `synchronized` block) or `wait` (which attempts to re-acquire the lock when it awakens.)

By contrast, the `Lock` and `Condition` interfaces from `java.util.concurrent` are presented as separate objects.  They behave similarly to monitors though (`Condition.await()` re-acquires the lock and may need to contend with a `Lock.lock()` by another thread.)

Answer (score 1):

You can *not* acquire a monitor by using `wait()`. Quite the opposite: you first have to acquire the monitor using `synchronized` *before* you can use `wait()` on it, otherwise you will get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

So the distinction you describe does not exist.